# Twilio - Generating an access token in a for loop is giving me the same token

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I've been debugging all day as to why my app isn't working and I FINALLY figured out that my for loop isn't generating a new token in each iteration. Could someone please help me figure out why?

```
var token_array = [];

console.log(invited_friends.length);

for (let b = 0; b < invited_friends.length; b++){
            let accessToken = new AccessToken(
                                ACCOUNT_SID,
                                API_KEY_SID,
                                API_KEY_SECRET
                              );

            accessToken.identity = invited_friend_ids;
            let grant = new VideoGrant();
            grant.room = room_name;
            accessToken.addGrant(grant);
            let token = accessToken.toJwt();
            console.log('ACCESS TOKEN RETURNING:' + token);
            token_array.push(token);
}
```

Comment: so is your invited_friend_ids different? or same?

Comment: different every time, ```invited_friends.length``` returns 5

Comment: then the access tokens are different, check the full access token(atleast the last part). Because the first pat will be same for all the tokens as it has the `jwt` header value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like you are assigning the same identity for each token. Given everything else is the same, that is perhaps why they are coming out the same.

You assign the identity like this:

```js
accessToken.identity = invited_friend_ids;
```

But that isn't using your loop variable `b`. Should it be this instead?

```js
accessToken.identity = invited_friend_ids[b];
```